# How can I select an element with multiple classes in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What would be the proper CSS selector to target the following tag:

```
<nav class="twelve-col col main-menu">
```

Would the proper selector just be:

```css
.twelve-col col main-menu {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You should combine individual class names using `.`:

```
.twelve-col.col.main-menu
```

Comment: Ah, i see. Now does it matter in the css if it says <nav class="twelve-col col main-menu"> or <div class="twelve-col col main-menu">

Comment: If it says what? `:)` I mean, what do you mean? Both are same no?

Comment: Sorry, refresh the page - I was editing - sorry

Comment: ok so it wouldnt be .nav.twelve-col.col.main-menu {

Comment: @BillWentworth It's not `.nav.` but it's just `nav.` for Tag Selectors. `.` is used for classes and `#` is used for ids.

Comment: @BillWentworth In your case, you can also use `nav.twelve-col.col.main-menu`

Comment: Oh, ok. so <header class="container"> would be header.container{}

Comment: `.container` or `header.container`

Comment: But if there was a another container class in my site I would also be targeting that as well with just .container{} but header.container{} would exclusively target that one, correct? I will leave you positive feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

No. Your selector is trying to find `main-menu` INSIDE `col` which is INSIDE `twelve-col`. But you are looking for element, that has `twelve-col col main-menu` classes the same time, so use `.twelve-col.col.main-menu`

However try BEM methodology, where you use just one class to make all your selectors same specificity (http://getbem.com)

Answer (score 0):

The most effective selector will be `nav.twelve-col.col.main-menu` you can also use `nav.main-menu` which makes some sense.